# Tried to install python 3.7.0 got build failed

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyenv

Iam trying to install python 3.7.0 in ubuntu using "pyenv intall 3.7.0" Command. but got build failed.

```
root@Hp:/home/shiva# pyenv install 3.7.0
Downloading Python-3.7.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.0...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20230210140013.813
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230210140013.813.log

Last 10 log lines:
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
        case upgrade in \
                upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
                install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
        esac; \
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20230210140013.813/Python-3.7.0 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
                $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Segmentation fault
make: *** [Makefile:1122: install] Error 139
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this seems to be in the C-compiler automatically selected and used for the build.  You may force the C-Compiler to clang with

```
$ sudo apt install clang -y
$ CC=clang pyenv install 3.7.0
```

Ref: [#2239](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2239#issuecomment-1079275184) on pyenv GitHub.